# Join query in PostgreSQL using Python Flask sqlalchemy orm

Tags: python, postgresql, join, flask, sqlalchemy

I have two tables X and Y.

X has two columns id and name,
Y has three columns id, city, country

I need to make a join query and take city and country values corresponding to its name using id. `id` is a foreign key.

I tried directly in PostgreSQL with this query,

```
select * from x inner join y on x.name = 'xyz'
```

It's giving exact result. But while trying the same query using sqlalchemy orm in Python flask app it's not. I'm new to Python and Flask framework. I don't know how to achieve it.

I declared table definition and serialize function in a separate python file inside my models directory.

In my main.py file, I'm importing that model and tried this kind of querying, But it's not working.

```
from models import x, y

response = x.query.join(y).filter_by(name=name).all()
```

I'm getting error message like this,

> sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError
>
> InvalidRequestError: Could not find a FROM clause to join from.  Tried joining to `<class 'models.y'>`, but got: Can't find any foreign key relationships between 'x' and 'y'.

Comment: I don't know much about python or sqlachemy, but I know something of orms.
According the documentation, and the log outputo, you need to set the relationship in your model.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/join_conditions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer to write out regular SQL statements, then why not use SQLAlchemy to do just that. It's not a requirement that you use chain methods like `join`, `filter_by`, etc to query your database.

In order to answer this question, I need to make some assumptions about what's in your `models` file. I'll assume it's something like this:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import datetime

db = SQLAlchemy()

class BaseModel(db.Model):
    """Base data model for all objects"""
    # more code here

class x(BaseModel, db.Model):
    # more table setup code here

class y(BaseModel, db.Model):
    # more table setup code here
```

If that's the case, then here's what you can do to execute plain old parameterized SQL statements::

```
from flask import Flask
from models import db
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'your_database_connection_string'
db.init_app(app)

result = db.session.execute("select * from x inner join y on x.name = :name", {"name":"xyz"})

# If no rows were returned in the result, return an empty list
if result.returns_rows == False:
    response = []

# Convert the response to a plain list of dicts
else:
    response = [dict(row.items()) for row in result]

# Output the query result as JSON
print(json.dumps(response))
```

I find this method of running SQL queries in Flash with SQLAlchemy far easier to follow and understand than trying to use all of the different method chaining that you were attempting in your original post.

Comment: Note that `result.returns_rows` is always true for a `SELECT`, so the test is redundant.

Comment: The idea is that you could use the same pattern for inserts, updates and deletes too.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible to avoid the ORM alltogether like in Elliot's example, the ORM does have its advantages if the database is small. The most convenient way to solve your problem is by adding a [relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html). You can then query the results by, for example:

```
tree = db.session.query(Tree).first()
for leaf in tree.leaves:
    print(leaf.id)
```

If you cannot create the relationship, the proper syntax for a join is as follows:

```
db.session.query(Leaf).join(Tree,Leaf.tree_id==Tree.id)
```